# Error with Android gradle "Cause: startup failed: build file"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

My app gradle does not compile.

It marks the next error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ji0em.png)

And my full gradle code is:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "formiik.com.mobiik.www"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 19
            versionCode 160
            versionName "5.3.desa"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
        dexOptions {
            incremental true
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
        lintOptions {
            disable 'MissingTranslation'
        }
}


def openCVAndroidSdkDir = "/Users/jonathan/Development/Formiik/Desarollo/formiik-android-s/Formiik/opencv_sdk/sdk/native"

android.ndk {
    moduleName = "native"
    cppFlags += "-I${file(openCVAndroidSdkDir + "/jni/include")}".toString()
    cppFlags += "-frtti"
    cppFlags += "-fexceptions"
    ldLibs += ["log", "opencv_java3"]
    stl    = "gnustl_static"
}

android.productFlavors {

    create("arm") {
        ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi"
        ndk.ldFlags += "-L${file('src/main/jniLibs/armeabi')}".toString()
    }
    create("arm7") {
        ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"
        ndk.ldFlags += "-L${file('src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a')}".toString()
    }
    create("arm8") {
        ndk.abiFilters += "arm64-v8a"
        ndk.ldFlags += "-L${file('src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a')}".toString()
    }
}
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':volley')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.crittercism:crittercism-android-agent:5.+'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.zendesk:sdk:1.3.2.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.cocosw:undobar:1.+@aar'
    compile 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.ocpsoft:ocpsoft-pretty-time:1.0.7'
    compile 'in.srain.cube:ultra-ptr:1.0.10'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.6'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.+'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
}
```

I'm trying to integrate another project with the same gradle structure (that project works fine). but in this new project I get that error. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have enough reputation to comment yet, but have you tried `Build > Clean`? That can fix a bunch of issues with Gradle, especially those related to generated files.